# Dropdown DOM not updating after filteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to filter options in my `dropdown` menu on a selection of a `checkbox` using `javascript` and `jQuery` but it doesn't seem to work. It either hides everything for which the filter applies even when on change.

The drop down is populated via an Array using the same javascript itself.

```
    function fillJobs(jobStatus){
        var select = document.getElementById("candidateAssociatedJobs");
        select.innerHTML = '';
        let companies = {
"A":[
    {"jobid":"1","company":"A","role":"A Role 1","status":"Closed"},
    {"jobid":"2","company":"A","role":"A Role 2","status":"Active"},
    {"jobid":"3","company":"A","role":"A Role 3","status":"Active"}
],
"B":[
    {"jobid":"4","company":"B","role":"B Role 1","status":"Closed"},
    {"jobid":"5","company":"B","role":"B Role 2","status":"Closed"},
    {"jobid":"6","company":"B","role":"B Role 3","status":"Active"}
]}

        Object.keys(companies).forEach(company => {

            let optGroup = document.createElement("optgroup");
            optGroup.label = company;

            companies[company].forEach(job => {

                if(jobStatus === "Active"){
                    if(job.status === "Active"){
                        let opt = job;
                        let el = document.createElement("option");
                        el.textContent = opt.role;
                        el.setAttribute('data-tokens', company);
                        el.value = opt.jobid;
                        optGroup.appendChild(el);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    let opt = job;
                    let el = document.createElement("option");
                    el.textContent = opt.role;
                    el.setAttribute('data-tokens', company);
                    el.value = opt.jobid;
                    optGroup.appendChild(el);
                }

            })

            select.append(optGroup);
            console.log(select);

        })

    }

    let jobStatusCheck = "Active";

    fillJobs(jobStatusCheck);

    $('#activeJobsCheck').change(e =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        if(jobStatusCheck === "Active"){
            jobStatusCheck = "Closed"
            fillJobs(jobStatusCheck);
        }
        else{
            jobStatusCheck = "Active"
            fillJobs(jobStatusCheck);
        }
    })
```

On console logging my `select` the options do show up properly, but the DOM isn't getting updated.

Comment: Your code works if I try it, so it must be something else. Do you get any other messages? Can you provide an example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I have updated the companies and yeah, I am using bootstrap-select for select :/ https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have modified your underlying `select`, call the bootstrap-select `refresh` to make it reflect the changes at the end of your method:

```js
function fillJobs(jobStatus){
    var select = document.getElementById("candidateAssociatedJobs");
    select.innerHTML = '';
    let companies = {
        "A": [
            {"jobid":"1","company":"A","role":"A Role 1","status":"Closed"},
            {"jobid":"2","company":"A","role":"A Role 2","status":"Active"},
            {"jobid":"3","company":"A","role":"A Role 3","status":"Active"}
        ],
        "B": [
            {"jobid":"4","company":"B","role":"B Role 1","status":"Closed"},
            {"jobid":"5","company":"B","role":"B Role 2","status":"Closed"},
            {"jobid":"6","company":"B","role":"B Role 3","status":"Active"}
        ]
    };

    Object.keys(companies).forEach(company => {

        let optGroup = document.createElement("optgroup");
        optGroup.label = company;

        companies[company].forEach(job => {

            if(jobStatus === "Active"){
                if(job.status === "Active"){
                    let opt = job;
                    let el = document.createElement("option");
                    el.textContent = opt.role;
                    el.setAttribute('data-tokens', company);
                    el.value = opt.jobid;
                    optGroup.appendChild(el);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                let opt = job;
                let el = document.createElement("option");
                el.textContent = opt.role;
                el.setAttribute('data-tokens', company);
                el.value = opt.jobid;
                optGroup.appendChild(el);
            }

        })

        select.append(optGroup);
        $(select).selectpicker('refresh');
    })
}

let jobStatusCheck = "Active";

fillJobs(jobStatusCheck);

$('#activeJobsCheck').change(e =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    if(jobStatusCheck === "Active"){
        jobStatusCheck = "Closed"
        fillJobs(jobStatusCheck);
    }
    else{
        jobStatusCheck = "Active"
        fillJobs(jobStatusCheck);
    }
});

$(function() {
  $('#candidateAssociatedJobs').selectpicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<select id="candidateAssociatedJobs"></select>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="activeJobsCheck">
  Show all jobs
</label>
```

Comment: On doing that none of the options show up, Should i refresh and then append?

Comment: refresh and append also result in no options being displayed.

Comment: @Nithin Something else might be wrong in your code then. I have updated my answer to include your code, and it works for me (Chrome).

Comment: Thanks JLe, It works. Turns out it was the async nature that was throwing errors, I managed to solve it via async/await. Will check the above solution as well. Thanks.